# hex string arithmetic in c++

Tags: c++, hex, bignum, multiprecision

I want to do basic arithmetic (addition, subtraction and comparison) with 64 digit hex numbers represented as strings. for example

`"ffffa"+"2" == "ffffc"`

Since binary representation of such a number requires 256 bits, I cannot convert the string to basic integer types. one solution is to use `gmp` or `boost/xint` but they are too big for this simple functionality.

Is there a lightweight solution that can help me?

Comment: "Since binary representation of such a number requires 256 bits" How so? The maximum number of bits required to do your example is bounded by 20 bits, which fits perfectly well into a standard `int`.

Comment: @Jodocus The example requires 20 bits. Anyway, I guess one would assume the example is just an example.

Comment: @Jodocus @Acorn `64 digit hex` and `such a number requires 256 bits`. I think the OPs example is just an example and the OP means that 64 digit hex number needs 256 bits in binary representation.

Comment: *Is there a lightweight solution that can help me* -- This is really no different than the typical "big integer" class, except that the addition, carry, etc. are base 16.  Tons of code is available that implements this in base 10, thus should be easy to retrofit for base 16.

Comment: @Jodocus `16^64==2^256`

Comment: The fact that they're represented as strings doesn't say you need to do arithmetic byte-by-byte. You could also parse them to 4 unsigned integers, and implement all operations on them, [like that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f1a1162c563c23). But yeah, probably some off-the-shelf bigint library would work better.

Comment: One possibility is to create your own object with std::array of char (or int) inside. This should simplify the implementation. If you are not allowed to use a library, it should be rather simple to implement anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a library which will handle the strings with conversion between hex to int and will add one char at a time, taking care of overflow. It took minutes to implement such an algorithm:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace hexstr {
    char int_to_hexchar(int v) {
        if (0 <= v && v <= 9) {
            return v + '0';
        } else {
            return v - 10 + 'a';
        }
    }
    int hexchar_to_int(char c) {
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            return c - '0';
        } else {
            return c - 'a' + 10;
        }
    }
    int add_digit(char a, char b) {
        return hexchar_to_int(a) + hexchar_to_int(b);
    }
    void reverseStr(string& str) { 
        int n = str.length(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) 
            swap(str[i], str[n - i - 1]); 
    }
    void _add_val_to_string(string& s, int& val) {
        s.push_back(int_to_hexchar(val % 16));
        val /= 16;
    }
    string add(string a, string b)
    {
        auto ita = a.end();
        auto itb = b.end();
        int tmp = 0;
        string ret;

        while (ita != a.begin() && itb != b.begin()) {
            tmp += add_digit(*--ita, *--itb);
            _add_val_to_string(ret, tmp);
        }
        while (ita != a.begin()) {
            tmp += hexchar_to_int(*--ita);
            _add_val_to_string(ret, tmp);
        }
        while (itb != b.begin()) {
            tmp += hexchar_to_int(*--itb);
            _add_val_to_string(ret, tmp);
        }
        while (tmp) {
            _add_val_to_string(ret, tmp);
        }

        reverseStr(ret);

        return ret;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout 
        << "1bd5adead01230ffffc" << endl
        << hexstr::add(
                std::string() + "dead0000" + "00000" + "ffffa", 
                std::string() + "deaddead" + "01230" + "00002"
        ) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This can be optimized, the reversing string maybe can be omitted and some cpu cycles and memory allocations spared. Also error handling is lacking. It will work only on implementations that use ASCII table as the character set and so on... But it's as simple as that. I guess this small lib can handle any hex strings way over 64 digits, depending only on the host memory.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing addition, subtraction and comparison over fixed-base numeric strings yourself should be quite easy.

For instance, for addition and subtraction, simply do it as you would in paper: start on the right-hand end of both strings, parse the `char`s, compute the result, then carry over, etc. Comparison is even easier, and you go left-to-right.

Of course, all this is assuming you don't need performance (otherwise you should be using a proper library).